# How do I add a custom css to all posts without affecting homepage css?

Tags: php, customization, css, html

As the title says, How can I add a custom CSS to all posts without affecting homepage CSS on WordPress?

And I know that some plugins like "WP Add Custom CSS" would work for this and I am actually using it, and it does work but, what I want to do is give all my posts the same exact code, I don't want to give every post manually the same code over and over.

Because if I wanted to change this code later on, then I will have to go back and edit every post that I made with this new code change.

For example, I have this CSS code:

```
.post-meta {
    margin-right: 0px !important;
}
```

Every post needs to have this code but without affecting homepage CSS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, WordPress sets various classes to `<body>` depending on which page, template, parent, .. you are on. For a single post, some of these are `single` and `single-post`, so you could use the following

```
body.single.single-post .post-meta {
    margin-right: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: And what if I wanted the opposite? I want only the homepage to be changed only.

Comment: Never mind I got that, I could use `.homepage`

Comment: @DragoonShimizu Sorry, just got back but glad you found the solution yourself! It can be interesting to check the `<body>` of specific pages. WordPress will almost always set specific classes (at least the specific id), which you can use in your CSS

Answer (score 1):

Most themes add the class of `home` to the body element on the home page, so providing yours does you can easily target everywhere else except for the home page using the `:not()` pseudo-class.

`body:not(.home) .post-meta { ... }`

Hope that helps